# Include header on html page on print on different sides for odd and even

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I am creating an html page and one of the tasks is to include the company's logo as a header **on print.**

The issue is that this header is not there in the first couple of pages, say the first 10 pages. After that, this header is included, but it is on the right-hand side on page numbers 11, 13, 15, 17, etc, and on the left-hand side on page numbers 12, 14, 16, 18, etc.

How can we achieve this scenario? Many thanks in advance

Comment: Please add a piece of code or a demo to understand the issue

Answer (score 0):

if your website has  page number
suppose, `<div id="PageNoId"></div>`

and you have header
`<header id="headerId" onload="myHeaderFunction()">Company Logo</header>`

then,

```
function myHeaderFunction(){

    var pageno = document.getElementById("PageNoId");

    if(pageno > 11)
    {
        /*hide heder for first 10*/
        document.getElementById("headerId").style.dispaly = "none";
        return;
    }
    if(pageno % 2 == 0){
        document.getElementById("headerId").style.dispaly = "block";
        document.getElementById("headerId").style.textalign = "left";
        return;
    }
    if(pageno % 2 != 0){
        document.getElementById("headerId").style.dispaly = "block";
        document.getElementById("headerId").style.textalign = "right";
        
    }
}
```

note: your question is not clear, i want to give you a idea , how it will work. thank you